# Firebase Android Chat Realtime Functionality not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a Firebase chat application. I downloaded a demo and tried to complete it (http://myapptemplates.com/simple-android-chat-app-tutorial-firebase-integration/)

I was able to send and receive messages but the problem is I have to actually exit the chatbox and load it again to see new messages. Another thing is all registered users both sends and receives the same messages rather than one recipient and sender only. I am new to Firebase so I'm really having a hard time fixing it.

Here is the `sendMessage()` function:

```
    private void sendMessage() {
    if (txt.length() == 0)
        return;

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txt.getWindowToken(), 0);

    String s = txt.getText().toString();

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null) {
        final Conversation conversation = new Conversation(s,
                Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),
                user.getUid(),
                buddy.getId(),
                "");
        conversation.setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_SENDING);
        convList.add(conversation);
        final String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("messages")
                .push().getKey();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").child(key)
                .setValue(conversation)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                   convList.get(convList.indexOf(conversation)).setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_SENT);
                                               } else {
                                                   convList.get(convList.indexOf(conversation)).setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_FAILED);
                                               }
                                               FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                                       .getReference("messages")
                                                       .child(key).setValue(convList.get(convList.indexOf(conversation)))
                                                       .addOnCompleteListener(new
                                                                                      OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                                          @Override
                                                                                          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                                                              adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                                                          }
                                                                                      });

                                           }
                                       }
                );
    }
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    txt.setText(null);
}
```

Here is the `loadConversationList()`

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(). getReference("messages").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Conversation conversation = ds.getValue(Conversation.class);
                    if ((conversation.getReceiver().contentEquals(user.getUid()) && conversation.getSender().contentEquals(buddy.getId()))
                            || (conversation.getSender().contentEquals(user.getUid()) && (conversation.getReceiver().contentEquals(buddy.getId())))) {
                        convList.add(conversation);
                        if (lastMsgDate == null
                                || lastMsgDate.before(conversation.getDate()))
                            lastMsgDate = conversation.getDate();

                        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've added a `SingleValueListener`. This will read the data only once. To get the realtime functionality, you should add a `ValueEventListener` like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(). getReference("messages").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```